# What if you can use async/await to make React's setState synchronous

Tags: reactjs

Since React's `setState` function is asynchronous and therefore, you cannot access newly updated state within the same function calling `this.setState`, what are the pros and cons of using async/await on setState, like `await this.setState({ newState });`

Comment: if you really wanted to you could wrap your setstate with a promise.. and resolve when the setstate is completed. that would be something you could use async await on :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell, you don't need to wrap it into a promise and use await since it already provides a callback to take actions when setState is completed

Answer (score 17):

There are no pros because `this.setState` doesn't return a promise and `await`ing it doesn't serve a good purpose.

It should be promisified in order to be used with `await`:

```
const setStateAsync = updater => new Promise(resolve => this.setState(updater, resolve))
```

There usually won't be much use of this due to how `setState` is usually used. If there's a need to rely on previously set state, updater function may be used.

Comment: Here is a sandbox using the same idea https://codesandbox.io/s/4wxoyrpknw

Answer (score 10):

`await` keyword needs to be used for an expression that returns a Promise, and although `setState` is async, it doesn't return a Promise and hence await won't work with it. `setState` provides a `callback` to track if it has completed.

You would use callback like

```
this.setState({
   newState
}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.newState)
})
```

[`Here is a demo`](https://codesandbox.io/s/ypy7ny58kz) which shows that setState doesn't work with `async await`

Comment: It works if you promisify the state correctly and then await on it. https://codesandbox.io/s/4wxoyrpknw

Comment: @nrgwsth I know it will work if you promisify the action, but you don't need to do it as it provided a callback already and wrapping it into a promise just so that you can make use of await don't make sense. It would introduce too may complications in your app. setState callback along with other lifecycle methods tend to solve most of the problems