# Does this.setState return promise in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await, setstate

I made my `componentWillMount()` async. Now I can using `await` with the `setState`.

Here is the sample code:

```
componentWillMount = async() => {
  const { fetchRooms } = this.props
  await this.setState({ })
  fetchRooms()
}
```

So question here is `this.setState` returns promise because I can use `await` with it?

***Edit***

When I put await then it runs in a sequence `1, 2, 3` And when I remove await then it runs `1, 3, 2`??

```
  componentWillMount = async() => {
    const { fetchRooms } = this.props
    console.log(1)
    await this.setState({ } => {
      console.log(2)
    })
    console.log(3)
    fetchRooms()
  }
```

Comment: `setState` does not return a promise, but your code should work fine without `await` before it. What is it that you want to achieve? You can also make the `componentWillMount` method async instead of creating a property for every instance. `async componentWillMount() { ... }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53080701/what-if-you-can-use-async-await-to-make-reacts-setstate-synchronous

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`setState` is usually not used with promises because there's rarely such need. If the method that is called after state update (`fetchRooms`) relies on updated state (`roomId`), it could access it in another way, e.g. as a parameter.

`setState` uses callbacks and doesn't return a promise. Since this is rarely needed, creating a promise that is not used would result in overhead.

In order to return a promise, `setState` can be promisified, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53080853/3731501).

Posted code works with `await` because it's a hack. `await ...` is syntactic sugar for `Promise.resolve(...).then(...)`. `await` produces one-tick delay that allows to evaluate next line after state update was completed, this allows to evaluate the code in intended order. This is same as:

```
this.setState({ roomId: room && room.roomId ? room.roomId : 0 }, () => {
  console.log(2)
})

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(3)
});
```

There's no guarantee that the order will stay same under different conditions. Also, first `setState` callback isn't a proper place to check whether a state was updated, this is what second callback is for.

Comment: In my opinion the main need of a promise with setState is a subjective thing :  the .then syntax is very elegant and easy to understand. (more than a second callable post updating argument)

Comment: @Xmanoux It looks neat but one-tick delay can interfere with React lifecycle if it's unintentional. A lot of things can happen during 1 tick. More specifically, the component could be unmounted (this will happen in the OP because componentWillMount shouldn't be async). There's a known problem with promise control flow in general because promises are not cancellable and aren't aware of component lifecycle. It just becomes more prominent if promises are used in places where they aren't necessary.

Answer (score 26):

You can promisify `this.setState` so that you can use the React API as a promise. This is how I got it to work:

```js
class LyricsGrid extends Component {

  setAsyncState = (newState) =>
    new Promise((resolve) => this.setState(newState, resolve));
```

Later, I call `this.setAsyncState` using the standard Promise API:

```js
this.setAsyncState({ lyricsCorpus, matrix, count })
  .then(foo1)
  .then(foo2)
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

Comment: You don't have to bind arrow function methods so you don't even need to write constructor by hand. They capture the this of surrounding context automatically.

Comment: they don't have an inner-this, so it just uses the outer this

Comment: Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

Answer (score 15):

setState does not return a promise.

setState has a callback.

```
this.setState({
    ...this.state,
    key: value,
}, () => {
    //finished
});
```

Comment: If you use hooks, there is no callback for setState.

Comment: @HasanSefaOzalp But you can use `effect` for that.

Comment: Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

Comment: @Danish my answer was about classed based component not for hooks.

Answer (score 4):

Don't think `setState` is returning a `Promise` but you can always do this

```
 await new Promise( ( resolve ) => 
     this.setState( {
         data:null,
     }, resolve )
 )
```

or you can make some utility function like this

```
const setStateAsync = ( obj, state ) => {
    return new Promise( ( resolve ) =>
        obj.setState( state , resolve )
    )
}
```

and use it inside a React.Component like this:

```
await setStateAsync(this,{some:'any'})
```

Answer (score 3):

It does not return a promise.

You can slap the `await` keyword in front of any expression. It has no effect if that expression doesn't evaluate to a promise.

`setState` accepts a callback.

Comment: No I can see the change. Let me clear you the question again. when I put the `await` in front of `this.setState` it stops the code. I checked it by putting logs one before and after `this.setState`. And that's why I have asked question here.

Answer (score 2):

#### You can simple customize a Promise for setState

```js
  componentWillMount = async () => {
    console.log(1);
    await this.setRooms();
    console.log(3);
  };

  setRooms = () => {
    const { fetchRooms } = this.props;
    return fetchRooms().then(({ room }) => {
      this.setState({ roomId: room && room.roomId ? room.roomId : 0 }, _ =>
        console.log(2)
      );
    });
  };
```

Or

```js
  setRooms = async () => {
    const { fetchRooms } = this.props;
    const { room } = await fetchRooms();

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.setState({ roomId: room && room.roomId ? room.roomId : 0 }, _ =>
        resolve()
      );
    });
  };
```

Hope this help =D

Answer (score 0):

Simpler way to answer this question is we can use `promisify` function present in pre-installed `util` library of node.js and then use it with the *await* keyword.

```
import {promisify} from 'util';

updateState = promisify(this.setState);
await this.updateState({ image: data });
```