# React how to store state value onSubmit

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, setstate

I am trying to store the value of one state property within another on submit, so that I can submit a URL friendly slug to my database.

Below is part of the function that is called when my form is submitted. Currently the form submits to a database (Firestore) and it works fine. However, I need to collect the value that a user inputs into streetAddress, slugify it, and then submit that to my database as its own slug field using the slug property of my state.

The problem I have, is I don't know how to do this. I've tried a few ways and slug is submitted to the database, but always with an empty value. Below is how I have attempted it.

```
onSubmit = event => {
const {  reviewTitle, reviewContent, streetAddress, cityOrTown, 
        countyOrRegion, postcode, startDate, endDate, landlordOrAgent, rating, slug } = this.state;

this.setState({
    slug: streetAddress
})


// Creating batch to submit to multiple Firebase collections in one operation
var batch = this.props.firebase.db.batch();
var propertyRef = this.props.firebase.db.collection("property").doc();
var reviewRef = this.props.firebase.db.collection("reviews").doc();

batch.set(propertyRef, { streetAddress, cityOrTown,
    countyOrRegion, postcode, slug,
    uid });
batch.set(reviewRef, { startDate, endDate,
    reviewTitle, reviewContent, rating, 
    uid });
batch.commit().then(() => {
    this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
    });
    event.preventDefault();
};
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction or tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`this.setState` is a async function. So what you can do is calling a callback function after the state is updated.

```
this.setState({
    slug: streetAddress
}, () => {
    // Creating batch to submit to multiple Firebase collections in one operation
    var batch = this.props.firebase.db.batch();
    var propertyRef = this.props.firebase.db.collection("property").doc();
    var reviewRef = this.props.firebase.db.collection("reviews").doc();

    batch.set(propertyRef, {
        streetAddress, cityOrTown,
        countyOrRegion, postcode, slug,
        uid
    });
    batch.set(reviewRef, {
        startDate, endDate,
        reviewTitle, reviewContent, rating,
        uid
    });
    batch.commit().then(() => {
        this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
    });
    event.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this post says setState doesn't return a promise - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53409325/does-this-setstate-return-promise-in-react#:~:text=setState%20uses%20callbacks%20and%20doesn,as%20suggested%20in%20this%20answer. - I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: Yes. I updated the answer. Did you try this way by passing a callback function

Comment: I used a different solution, a variable to store the slugified result of streetAddress, like this: // Creating property slug
    var slug = slugify(this.state.streetAddress); - it seemed easier to me, then I just pass in the slug variable when I submit to database.