# React props don't renders on compomnent mount

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, store, reselect

I have Redux store reselect `tbodyCommand.reducer.js`  with Redux store with `MAKE_TBODY` case where I am calling `makeTbodyArray()` functions with subscriber in it and for() cycle. This stuff is connected with **TableBody component** (child of Table component) where I am trying to call this **props function** (`makeTbody()` that is dispatched like `MAKE_TBODY()`) and by calling `componentDidMount` it have only console logs and loads `comVal` props with array in debug tools in state, but not rendering at all in component (`componentWillReceiveProps` exists and works but not rendering all coming from props array).

So the main goal is to render `comVal` props in table on component first load. If i will change something in sandbox / re - type it and save it will re-render it with props correct rendering (but it wan't be formally first - time - app - rendering, so here props coming I guess from **prevProps**).

https://gvh5n.csb.app/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through a lot of trying and bad code decisions get two answers on this difficult situation. First one is to look on https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-query `react-query` library and it's examples. And the variant that I used for me is just to make a `promise` and setStateAsync function to make state editable in promise from this question [Does this.setState return promise in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53409325/does-this-setstate-return-promise-in-react). Here is my code https://xmzx3.csb.app/ .
So the `promise` makes available in `componentDidMount` function to re-render component after getting props function results.